# What is the étale fundamental group of projective spaces over finite fields?

Tags: etale-cohomology, fundamental-group, projective-varieties, etale-covers

Is there any convenient way to understand the étale fundamental group of projective spaces over finite fields, in particular, the étale fundamental group of $\mathbf{P}^2_{\mathbf{F}_q}$?

Comment: This is just the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}/\mathbb{F}_q) $.

Comment: The fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$ can be computed by noting that the fundamental group $\mathbb{P}^1_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$ is trivial, that the fundamental group of a direct product is the direct product of the fundamental groups and that fundamental group is a birational invariant.

Comment: See for example Tag [0BTX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BTX) combined with the computation of $\pi_1(\mathbf P^n_{\bar k})$. (See [here](https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/p%c2%b9-is-simply-connected/) for a fun Riemann–Hurwitz-free proof when $n=1$.)

Comment: The fundamental group does not respect products. That requires either completeness or coprime characteristic, so it's ok here, but it's not true in general. If it were true, then the fundamental group of a group scheme would be abelian. But it's not for $\mathbb A^1$. @Faris